# Eager interpolation with just a closure behaves like a lazy one?

Tags: groovy

As part of learning Groovy, I'm trying to explore all intricate possibilities provided by string interpolation.
One of my little experiments gave results that don't make sense to me, and now I'm wondering whether I've completely misunderstood the basic concepts of lazy and eager interpolation in Groovy.

Here's the code I ran:

```groovy
def myVar1 = 3
// An eager interpolation containing just a closure.
def myStr = "${{->myVar1}}"
print ("Just after the creation of myStr\n")
print (myStr as String)
myVar1 += 1                                           // Bump up myVar1.
print ("\nJust after incrementing myVar1\n")
print (myStr as String)
```

Here's the output I got:

```
Just after the creation of myStr
3
Just after incrementing myVar1
4
```

Clearly, the closure has been invoked a second time. And the only way the closure could have been re-executed is by the containing interpolation getting re-evaluated. But then, the containing interpolation is, by itself, not a closure, though it *contains* a closure. So then, why is it getting re-evaluated?

Answer (score 5):

This is how `GString.toString()` method is implemented. If you take a look [at the source code](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_X/src/main/groovy/groovy/lang/GString.java#L150-L160) of `GString` class, you will find something like this:

```java
public String toString() {
    StringWriter buffer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        writeTo(buffer);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new StringWriterIOException(e);
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

public Writer writeTo(Writer out) throws IOException {
    String[] s = getStrings();
    int numberOfValues = values.length;
    for (int i = 0, size = s.length; i < size; i++) {
        out.write(s[i]);
        if (i < numberOfValues) {
            final Object value = values[i];

            if (value instanceof Closure) {
                final Closure c = (Closure) value;

                if (c.getMaximumNumberOfParameters() == 0) {
                    InvokerHelper.write(out, c.call());
                } else if (c.getMaximumNumberOfParameters() == 1) {
                    c.call(out);
                } else {
                    throw new GroovyRuntimeException("Trying to evaluate a GString containing a Closure taking "
                            + c.getMaximumNumberOfParameters() + " parameters");
                }
            } else {
                InvokerHelper.write(out, value);
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Notice that `writeTo` method examines what the values passed for interpolation are, and in case of closure, it invokes it. This is the way GString handles lazy-evaluation of interpolated values.

Now let's take a look at a few examples. Let's assume we want to print a GString and interpolate a value returned by some method call. This method will also print something to the console, so we can see if the method call was triggered eagerly or lazily.

### Ex.1: Eager evaluation

```
class GStringLazyEvaluation {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def var = 1

        def str = "${loadValue(var++)}"

        println "Starting the loop..."

        5.times {
            println str
        }

        println "Loop ended..."
    }

    static Integer loadValue(int val) {
        println "This method returns value $val"
        return val
    }
}
```

The output:

```
This method returns value 1
Starting the loop...
1
1
1
1
1
Loop ended...
```

The default eager behavior. The method `loadValue()` was invoked before we have printed out `str` to the console.

### Ex.2: Lazy evaluation

```
class GStringLazyEvaluation {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def var = 1

        def str = "${ -> loadValue(var++)}"

        println "Starting the loop..."

        5.times {
            println str
        }

        println "Loop ended..."
    }

    static Integer loadValue(int val) {
        println "This method returns value $val"
        return val
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Starting the loop...
This method returns value 1
1
This method returns value 2
2
This method returns value 3
3
This method returns value 4
4
This method returns value 5
5
Loop ended...
```

In the second example, we take advantage of lazy evaluation. We define `str` with a closure that invokes `loadValue()` method and this invocation is executed when we explicitly print the `str` to the console (to be more specific - when the `GString.toString()` method gets executed).

### Ex.3: Lazy evaluation and closure memoization

```
class GStringLazyEvaluation {

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def var = 1

        def closure = { -> loadValue(var++)}
        def str = "${closure.memoize()}"

        println "Starting the loop..."

        5.times {
            println str
        }

        println "Loop ended..."
    }

    static Integer loadValue(int val) {
        println "This method returns value $val"
        return val
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Starting the loop...
This method returns value 1
1
1
1
1
1
Loop ended...
```

And here is the example you most probably look for. In this example, we still take advantage of lazy evaluation thanks to the closure parameter. However, in this case, we use [closure's memoization feature](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/core-closures.html#_memoization). The evaluation of the string is postponed to the first `GString.toString()` invocation and closure's result gets memorized, so the next time it gets called it returns the result instead of re-evaluating the closure.

### What is the difference between `${{->myVar1}}` and `${->myVar1}`?

As it was mentioned earlier, `GString.toString()` method uses `GString.writeTo(out)` that [checks if the given placeholder stores a closure](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_5_X/src/main/groovy/groovy/lang/GString.java#L176-L202) for a lazy evaluation. Every GString instance store placeholder values in the `GString.values` array and it gets initialized during GString initialization. Let's consider the following example:

```groovy
def str = "${myVar1} ... ${-> myVar1} ... ${{-> myVar1}}"
```

Now let's follow `GString.values` array initialization:

```
${myVar1}      --> evaluates `myVar1` expression and copies its return value to the values array
${-> myVar1}   --> it sees this is closure expression so it copies the closure to values array
${{-> myVar1}} --> evaluates `{-> myVar1}` which is closure definition expression in this case and copies its return value (a closure) to the values array
```

As you can see, in the 1st and 3rd example it did exactly the same - it evaluated the expression and stored it in the `GString.values` array of type `Object[]`. And here is the crucial part: **the expression like `{->something}` is not a closure invocation expression**. The expression that evaluates the closure is

```
{->myVar1}()
```

or

```
{->myVar1}.call()
```

It can be illustrated with the following example:

```
def str = "${println 'B'; 2 * 4} ${{ -> println 'C'; 2 * 5}} ${{ -> println 'A'; 2 * 6}.call()}"

println str
```

Values initialization is as follows:

```
${println 'B'; 2 * 4}               ---> evaluates the expression which prints 'B' and returns 8 - this value is stored in values array.
${{ -> println 'C'; 2 * 5}}         ---> evaluates the expression which is nothing else than creation of a closure. This closure is stored in the values array.
${{ -> println 'A'; 2 * 6}.call()}" ---> evaluates the expression which creates a closure and then calls it explicitely. It prints 'A' and returns 12 which is stored in the values array at the last index.
```

That is why after `GString` object initialization we end up with `values` array like:

```
[8, script$_main_closure1, 12]
```

Now, the creation of this `GString` caused a side effect - the following characters shown on the console:

```
B
A
```

This is because the 1st and the 3rd values evaluation invoked `println` method call.

Now, when we finally call `println str` which invokes `GString.toString()` method, all values get processed. When the interpolation process starts it does the following:

```
value[0] --> 8 --> writes "8"
value[1] --> script$_main_closure1 --> invoke script$_main_closure1.call() --> prints 'C' --> returns 10 --> 10 --> writes "10"
value[2] --> 12 --> writes "12"
```

That is why the final console output looks like this:

```
B
A
C
8 10 12
```

This is why in practice expressions like `${->myVar1}` and `${{->myVar1}}` are similar. In the first case GString initialization does not evaluate the closure expression and puts it directly to the values array, in the second example placeholder gets evaluated and the expression it evalutes creates and returns the closure which then gets stored in the values array.

### Note on Groovy 3.x

If you try to execute the expression `${{->myVar1}}` in Groovy 3.x you will end up with the following compiler error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
General error during conversion: java.lang.NullPointerException

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.lambda$visitGstring$28(AstBuilder.java:3579)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.visitGstring(AstBuilder.java:3591)
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.visitGstring(AstBuilder.java:356)
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.GroovyParser$GstringContext.accept(GroovyParser.java:4182)
    at groovyjarjarantlr4.v4.runtime.tree.AbstractParseTreeVisitor.visit(AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java:20)
    at org.apache.groovy.parser.antlr4.AstBuilder.visit(AstBuilder.java:4287)
    .....
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:565)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:240)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.commandLineCompile(FileSystemCompiler.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.commandLineCompileWithErrorHandling(FileSystemCompiler.java:203)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.main(FileSystemCompiler.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.rootLoader(GroovyStarter.java:114)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter.main(GroovyStarter.java:136)

1 error
```

Comment: I'm afraid you've missed my question -- which is: Why is ${{->myVar1}} being treated as a lazy interpolation. AFAIK, ${->myVar1} should be treated as a lazy interpolation, but not ${{->myVar1}}

Comment: @fountainhead Where did you find the information that `${{->myVar1}}` evaluates in a different way than `${->myVar1}`? I couldn't find any information about that, and the compilation proves that there is no difference between both notations. Take a look at the updated example and the output it produces - https://gist.github.com/wololock/22ce1d2fd4c49222c4c4518c56b5671b Both variables in the GString are closure expressions of type `GStringLazyEvaluation$_main_closure1`. Also, keep in mind that notation `${{->myVar1}}` is valid only for Groovy 2.x. Groovy 3.x accepts only `${->myVar1}`.

Comment: As I understand, `${{->myVar1}}` consists of an outer _eager_ placeholder `${}`, enclosing a single expression `{->myVar1}`; and that enclosed single expression is an object of type `groovy.lang.Closure`. Which makes the whole thing just an __eager__ placeholder, which just __happens__ to have a closure as its enclosed expression, but it could just as well be enclosing any other (eg, numeric) expression. Since, it is an __eager__ placeholder, I expect it to be evaluated eagerly, rather than lazily.

Comment: Your assumption about enclosing expression is valid if you express it as `${->{->myVar1}}`, which is a closure expression that encapsulates inner closure expression. Inner closure expression does not get evaluated implicitly, but the outer (root) closure expression does. Otherwise `${{->myVar1}}` is the same as `${->myVar1}`. And this side effect only works in Groovy 2.x - in Groovy 3.x you will see a compilation error instead for `${{->myVar1}}` (expression like `${->{->myVar1}}` compiles without any issues in Groovy 3.x).

Comment: Pls help me take stock of which part of my understanding is _assumption_, and which is _fact_. **(1)** The expression `{->myVar1}` is a valid expression of the type `Closure`. **(2)** An expression of any type can be used inside the eager interpolation placeholder `${}` **(3)** In my code, `${{->myVar1}}` is an **eager** interpolation rather than a **lazy** one, since the outer `{` is **not** followed immediately by a `->`. Hence the question - why is it being evaluated lazily?

Comment: Also, could you please share the compiler error in 3.x for `${{->myVar1}}` ? I'm curious, because the expression seems to be syntactically valid, as well as unambiguous. Perhaps, the compiler error would provide some clue about what I'm missing.

Comment: From [this groovy lang doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_special_case_of_interpolating_closure_expressions), I understand that a `${}` placeholder in a `GString` will act as a lazy placeholder only if the outer `{` is followed immediately by a `->` (or by a single arg name and then a `->`). If the outer `{` in the `${}` placeholder is not followed by a `->` arrow (or by a single arg name and then a `->`), then the `${}` would be treated as an eager one. Please let me know me if I'm wrong on this

Comment: @fountainhead Check my updated answer. I've explained the major difference between both expressions. Your assumption about eager placeholder evaluation is correct, it is only false for closure definition expression - you assume that this expression evaluates closure instantly, and this is not true. Closure invocation requires explicit invocation like `closure()` or `closure.call()`.

Comment: I think it is wrong/inconsistent behavior of Groovy -- At GString coercion time, it is executing the Closure object `{->myVar}` enclosed within `${{->myVar1}}`. Instead, it should have done an eager evaluation of `{->myVar1}.toString()` (which is the `toString` method invoked on the enclosed `Closure` object), and stored the result of the `toString` in the **values** array, and simply printed that result at GString coercion time. The internal design details of the compiler might 'explain' the observed behavior, but IMHO, do not **justify** the behavior.

Comment: Also, the compilation error in Groovy 3.x appears more like a bug/crash of the compiler, rather than a useful communication to the programmer suggesting some correction in the code.

Comment: Just FYI, `{->myVar1}.toString()` does not invoke the closure, it prints closure anonymous class name instead. I won't argue if this is good or bad, you asked for an explanation why does this situation happen and you got it. I think this behavior is consistent at the level of expression evaluation. Feel free to register to Groovy's dev mailing list if you would like to get the insights from the compiler creators http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Groovy-Dev-f372993.html

Comment: Szymon, for this surprising groovy behavior, the explanation that I was looking for, was not in terms of how the compiler has implemented this surprising behavior, but in terms of groovy programming tenets, or in terms of consistency. Your detailed and meticulous responses helped me (immensely) in many other ways, though, and I'm genuinely thankful for that. I've now reported this as a bug in the official Apache Jira forum for Groovy [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8952).